# Unable to go to administration pages (access denied)

Tags: users

It seems I have some problems to access some functions. When I try to run my website 
I have these errors:

```
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'views_access' not found or invalid function name in D:\SVN\lancaster\Dev\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 452.
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'views_access' not found or invalid function name in D:\SVN\lancaster\Dev\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 452.
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'views_access' not found or invalid function name in D:\SVN\lancaster\Dev\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 452.
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'views_access' not found or invalid function name in D:\SVN\lancaster\Dev\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 452.
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'views_access' not found or invalid function name in D:\SVN\lancaster\Dev\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 452.
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'nodereference_autocomplete_access' not found or invalid function name in D:\SVN\lancaster\Dev\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 452.
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'views_access' not found or invalid function name in D:\SVN\lancaster\Dev\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 452.
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'views_access' not found or invalid function name in D:\SVN\lancaster\Dev\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 452.
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'views_access' not found or invalid function name in D:\SVN\lancaster\Dev\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 452.
warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'views_access' not found or invalid function name in D:\SVN\lancaster\Dev\drupal\includes\menu.inc on line 452.
You are not authorized to access this page.
```

I tried to check if all my modules were enabled, but I can't log in as administrator in my site too. When I do it, I get the following error:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: which server using?

Comment: Server : Apache!

Comment: Hello, and welcome on Drupal Answers. What is your question? Are you asking how you can check if those modules are enabled, or how you can fix those error messages? Are you asking how you can log in to that site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to do the following:

- backup your database
- truncate drupal cache tables using phpmyadmin ui or from mysql command line
- truncate role_permission table using phpmyadmin ui or from the mysql command line
- try to login using super administrator, the user with id 1
- if nothing change with you, try to install another drupal project and see if you get the same error messages; maybe you have an issue with your php version or configuration.

Comment: Truncating the role_permission table is not necessary, as the user #1 has every permission.

Comment: yes I agree with you, its just an option.